# Splitting columns with made with groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I can't seem to find a solution to my problem. I have used groupby and value_count to get all the results for each team but I can not find a way to split the column to make three new ones for (H = Win, D = Draw, A= Loss) the new column names.
I don't know if I am just serching for the wrong thing or the way I have it now will not work.

```
matchdata.groupby("HomeTeam")["FullTimeResult"].value_counts()
```

Results in:

```
HomeTeam     FullTimeResult
Arsenal      H                 10
             D                  6
             A                  3
Aston Villa  A                  9
             H                  7
             D                  3
```

Wanted output

```
HomeTeam      Win     Draw     Loss   
Arsenal        10      6         3
AstonVilla     7       3         9
eg...
```

Comment: I think  df.pivot_table will do both operations (aggregate and turn the values into columns)

Comment: chain that with `unstack()`.